# how to move my old php website to new domain?

Tags: php, cpanel

i have a simple timesheet program based on php, on my old domain (A) and I want to move it to my new domain's subdomain(B) that already has a wordpress website on its main domain.

i know how to add a subdomain, my question is about how to use my files backup and sql backups to migrate this site.

Answer (score 1):

Simply to transfer the website you have to copy everything from one place to the other (an ftp client might come in handy).
If you don't know how to create a subdomain the procedure changes according to your hosting / where you registered your domain